# In Java How do I create a new class of the same type as 'this' class? Java

Tags: java, class, instance

I have a simple scenario. I'd like to create a new instance of the class below.

```
class A implements Fancy {
    void my() {
        Fancy b = // new X(); where X could be A or B
    }
}
```

When you have a `B` which implements `Fancy` as well.

Comment: What is the question exactly? Why can't you just say Fancy b = new B() if B implements Fancy?

Comment: Because I dont want a B always I want the type that is running my.

Comment: Still not clear what you want!

Comment: Do you know the keyword this in Java? It refers to the running object. I want to instantiace a class of the same type as the running object. Do you understand now?

Comment: @antonioP upvoting... this can be useful...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an `abstract class AbstractFancy` with a `create` method:

```
abstract class AbstractFancy implements Fancy {
    abstract Fancy create();

    void my() {
        Fancy b = create();
        //....
    }
}
```

In each class implement the `create` method:

```
class A extends AbstractFancy {
    Fancy create() {
        return new A();
    }
}
class B extends AbstractFancy {
    Fancy create() {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Comment: `A implements Fancy` implies that `Fancy` is an `interface`, not an `abstract class`.

Comment: @Thilo: I changed `Fancy` to an `abstract class` so that I could add the `create` method directly. Updated anyways...

Comment: @dacwe your classes `A` and `B` should extend `AbstractFancy`, not `Fancy`.

Comment: @Jesper: Updated! Should never fallen for the pressure to edit in the first place...

Comment: @dacwe, Can I ask why is my question downvoted? What can immidate to mind was Fancy = new this; but ofcourse thats illegal.

Comment: @AntonioP: I have no idea, it's a really good question I think!

Comment: @dacwe, Im suprised. Your answer is perfect and is what I was looking for. Now the question is closed as unanswerable! Btw I only added a Fancy create(); in the interface and implemented it by returning new A() in As implementation and return new B() in Bs. Works perfectly! Thanks man

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want `my()` to be defined in a base class, like a `FancyAdapter`, which has different child classes, and you want it to create an instance of the actual concrete child class. If you can assume that all classes implementing `Fancy` have a default (no-argument) constructor:

```
Fancy b = (Fancy) getClass().newInstance();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
class A implements Fancy {
    void my() {
        Fancy b = (Fancy)getClass().newInstance();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reflectively? (not recommended)

```
Fancy b = this.getClass().newInstance();
```

This will work if there is a zero-argument based constructor (implicit or explicit). Make sure you do a `try {} catch{}` around the statement.

Other way:

```
class A implements Fancy, Cloneable {

    void my() {
        try {
            Fancy b = (Fancy) clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you would want a Builder that creates a new `Fancy` object.